# VSCode: tslint-language-service plugin shows lint hints as error and not warning

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I am using Visual Studio Code `1.12.1` with [Typescript](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/04/27/announcing-typescript-2-3/) `2.3.2` and the enabled plugin `tslint-language-service: 0.9.3` with `tslint: 5.2.0`

For some reason all the `tslint` hints are shown as errors with a red underline. I would like to have it as a warning with a green/yellow underline.

How can I do it? This is the plugin I am using with the new Typescript version https://github.com/angelozerr/tslint-language-service#vscode

Like in in the demo gif it should be green and not red

https://github.com/angelozerr/tslint-language-service/raw/master/images/TslintLanguageServiceDemoVSCode.gif

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To treat linting errors like warnings you should modify your tslint.json and include the following option: `"defaultSeverity": "warning"`. More info [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/).

But it looks like there is a bug in vscode-tslint. See the following [thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/issues/193)

Comment: That fixed it for me. Was perplexed by this change as well. Thanks!

Comment: Wow! This was driving me nuts!  Must have been a change in latest Angular CLI. Would give +5 if I could.